# How to set Tomcat 8 to recompile JSP on page hit for development server

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7

I have a developement server that was on Tomcat 6. I just installed Tomcat 8, and noticed that it no longer recompiles JSPs on page hit. What do I have to change in server.xml to get it to recompile them on page hit?

Note: Someone pointed me to http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/loader.html but I don't think that answers the question because I don't care about reloading jars or class files under `/WEB-INF/classes/` or `/WEB-INF/lib`, just recompiling JSPs.

And if for some reason this can't be done in Tomcat 8, can it be done in Tomcat 7?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tomcat 8 and 7 uses the Jasper 2 JSP Engine. One of changes was made in this version is:

> **Background JSP compilation**
>   If you make a change to a JSP page which had already been compiled Jasper 2 can recompile that page in
>   the background. The previously compiled JSP page will still be
>   available to serve requests. Once the new page has been compiled
>   successfully it will replace the old page. This helps improve
>   availability of your JSP pages on a production server.

To control this behavior you can use the following parameters (in `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/web.xml`):

> **checkInterval** - If development is false and checkInterval is greater than zero, background compiles are enabled. checkInterval is
>   the time in seconds between checks to see if a JSP page (and its
>   dependent files) needs to be recompiled. Default 0 seconds.
>
> **development** - Is Jasper used in development mode? If true, the frequency at which JSPs are checked for modification may be specified
>   via the modificationTestInterval parameter.true or `false`, default
>   `true`.

See more: [Jasper 2 JSP Engine How To](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/jasper-howto.html)

Comment: How do I configure this for a specific application, rather than changing it globally?

Comment: @nisargshah95 If your web application needs specific settings, copy the declaration of JspServlet in the `conf/web.xml` file into your own `WEB-INF/web.xml` and adjust it.

Comment: Do I need to copy all the settings from `JspServlet` declaration and then append my own to it or only keep the settings that I want to add in `WEB-INF/web.xml` and tomcat will automatically append it to its own `JspServlet` settings?

Comment: I have a local tomcat (xamp) and this development parameter is not set. Still tomcat recompiles the JSPs when they change.